# Compile on QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I tried to make a frame_generator with Qt and C++ programming on ubuntu 12.04. I have chosen to work into the kernel space with my OS. I needed to extract a struct from kernel located in skbuff.h on my kernel and I succeeded to resolve the dependency problem of skbuff.h and the other file.h of the kernel system, otherwise, my program on QtCreator have the ability to access to the different file.h that skbuff.h needed.

But when I compile it show me more than 500 error, from the different files.h that I am talking about, and when I see some errors I discovered that Qt Creator may not understand some code portion written into "C" as well as "#ifndef ..., #error ... " and many other problems.

QtCreator use GCC compiler and I don't really know what I should do.

Pro file:

```
QT += core
QT -= gui
TARGET = socket_buffer
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-26-generic/include/ \
    /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-26-generic/arch/x86/include/ \
TEMPLATE = app 
SOURCES += main.cpp \
    skb.cpp
HEADERS += \
    skb.h
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS = -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-26-generic/include/linux/
QMAKE_CFLAGS = -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-26-generic/include/linux/
```

Example errors:

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-26-generic/include/linux/jiffies.h:43: error: division by zero in #if
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-26-generic/include/linux/bitops.h:164: error: #error BITS_PER_LONG not 32 or 64
/usr/include/stdlib.h:337: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
```

Comment: Post some of the errors you are getting and post your `.pro` file.

Comment: file.pro

QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = socket_buffer
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-26-generic/include/ \
                /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-26-generic/arch/x86/include/ \

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp \
    skb.cpp

HEADERS += \
    skb.h
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS = -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-26-generic/include/linux/
QMAKE_CFLAGS = -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-26-generic/include/linux/

Comment: Ok, now post some of your error messages.

Comment: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-26-generic/include/linux/jiffies.h:43: error: division by zero in #if
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-26-generic/include/linux/bitops.h:164: error: #error BITS_PER_LONG not 32 or 64
/usr/include/stdlib.h:337: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
ps : it shows me more than 700 error :'(((